# customer process notification workflow

Tags: workflow, communication

I am looking for a software/app or cloud service that would help me manage the following scenario.

I have customers who would apply for a service, I need to update them every time there is a change in their application status.

1. Customer applies for service.
2. Customer registers name and contact info
3. I update them when the application moves to the next stage
4. Ask them to provide information if needed
5. Send them final delivery from the service
6. Customer confirms the completion and closes the process.

I have tried to research some ticket management systems and process workflows like Asante, Freshdesk, and the like, but they seem to be too complicated or overkill for my needs.

I would prefer something simple and light, if possible a WordPress addon. Or something that I can locally deploy on a self-hosted server.